# Can power be supplied to a lavalier via the connector?

Tags: microphone, power

I have a BOYA BY-M1 lavalier mic which has its own battery unit. However, I want to attempt to supply power through the 4 pole TRRS jack itself for a project. I had attempted solutions for similar topics but to no success.

**What I've tried**
[image]

Referring to the picture, I have confirmed that point 1 & 2 are for the sound signal, 3 is the ground and 4 is V+(supply). I attempted to connect a 1.5V AA to points 3 and 4 but it didn't work, I have also attempted to connect a resistor across point 3 and 4 before connecting the battery for a voltage drop but that didn't work as well. Base on me probing around in the battery unit, I can confirm that voltage is being supplied (1.5V).

So am I missing something here? I don't think supplying power should be that complicated but have been stuck here for a while, appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: This should be posted on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but you’ll probably get the same answer

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be possible. The power-adapter unit that sits between the connector and the mic is where the power comes from. It is not going to be possible to bypass this. Bear in mind that the TRRS connector is wired primarily to provide microphone input to a smartphone. The "Left and Right" (TR) is likely not connected to anything at all.